# R . Sum quotation marks

Tags: r

```
napis <- paste0("Ala","Ma","Kota","Tomek","ma","psa")
a6=length((table(strsplit(napis, ""))))
print(a6)#A
#b
c=max(table(unlist(strsplit(napis, ""))))
print(c)
print((which.max(c)))
```

Last print show value = 5

I want to show which letter occour 5 times ( It's "a") and I want to show it like "a"

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
names(which.max(table(unlist(strsplit(napis, "")))))
#[1] "a"
```